# Does samba have the ability to specify a backup location for files that are replaced/overwritten?

Tags: backup, samba

I want it so every time a client modifies an existing file from a samba share, samba, on the server, will make a backup copy of the file first. Either by making a backup or using some kind of hard-link mechanism.

Comment: Have you looked at Samba's [man pages](https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/)?

Comment: @JW0914 Yes but I don't know if I missed something. I looked for `backup` and `versioning` but no luck.